# .gitattributes using '* text=auto' with filters

Tags: git, line-endings, gitattributes, git-filter

In a cross-platform project, what is the right way to configure *CRLF normalization* for all text files '`* text=auto`' together with *'smudge' and 'clean' filters* for certain files '`*.h filter=myfilter`'?

Example:

```sh
# my .gitattributes
* text=auto           # in case people don't have core.autocrlf set
*.h filter=myfilter   # filter for header files
```

After adding `*.h filter=myfilter`, I am getting warnings like:

> ```
> warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in foo.h.
> The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
> ```

If I remove `*.h filter=myfilter`, the warning disappears. Why? Is this line disabling the *CRLF normalization* for *.h files?

#### Update

As to the warning, the filters use `sed` to replace tags in file header comments. When run on windows `sed` is converting `CRLF` to `LF`. This is where the warning is coming from. The solution is to run `sed` in binary mode (`--binary`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some experimentation produces rather confusing results.

[The gitattributes documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) says this up front:

> When more than one pattern matches the path, a later line overrides an earlier line. *This overriding is done per attribute.*

(emphasis mine)  This clearly implies that, while `*.h filter=myfilter` overrides any earlier match for the `filter` setting, it should *not* affect any earlier `* text=...` setting.

The actual check-in and check-out process seem to be well behaved: the earlier `* text=<whatever>` is obeyed.

Other commands, however, seem to treat the `filter` as overriding the `text`.  (This seems to be where the warning comes from.)

You can cure the problem in this case by writing:

```
*.h text=auto filter=myfilter
```

but in general this seems to violate the documented behavior.